# What qualifies as a good question for UX?

Tags: discussion

After looking at questions for a while, it seems like things really tend to focus on IxD and some visual design. I get the feeling that if I asked a question about architecture, human factors, or industrial design, my question would be flagged. What qualifies?

Here's a chart that describes UX, and it seems to be the best answer here:
http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-interaction-design-and-experience-design Do we like this definition of UX? Is this what UX is? Should this be a question on the actual site? (Vs on Meta.)

[image: UX chart]

Comment: Industrial design, HCI and more general human factors are perfectly on topic, though if you want more research based stuff on psychology/HCI stuff you might want to check out [cogsci.se] as well

Comment: I also disagree with the majority of the HCI bubble being outside the UX bubble.

Comment: Good to know -- I'll checkout the Cog Sci site. Sounds interesting. And yes, I didn't make the diagram so it's a bit off. But it's a good starting place for conversation. I'm finding it hard to imagine anything HCI related that doesn't fit under UX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the feeling you get is wrong :)

Off the top of my head:

[Why don't most elevator panels let you unselect](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/19612/why-dont-most-elevator-panels-let-you-unselect)

[Why do ATMs (Cash Machines) display a thank you message for so long?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/19612/why-dont-most-elevator-panels-let-you-unselect)

[Why don't ATMs give you cash before your card?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23462/why-dont-atms-give-you-cash-before-your-card)

[Why do most public toilet doors open inwards?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/18238/why-do-most-public-toilet-doors-open-inwards)

And more generally: [physical](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical), [information-architecture](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/information-architecture), [industrial-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/industrial-design).

Comment: Awesome -- thanks for the great links.

Comment: You're welcome :)